# How to inform Instagram of bogus password reset email without clicking link in email?

Tags: email, instagram, phishing, password-reset

I received a "password reset" email from Instagram that I did not request. The body of the email does actually state:

> If you didn't request a password reset, [let us know](https://example.com/)

And the "let us know" text is hyperlinked.

But as I don't fully trust the email I don't want to click the link in the email! (As the [Instagram help docs](https://help.instagram.com/670309656726033) state: "If you get a suspicious email or message claiming to be from Instagram, don't click any links or attachments.")

So, how can I inform Instagram of the unrequested/bogus password reset email without actually clicking the link in the email itself?

[image: Instagram password reset email]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Instagram Help Centre](https://help.instagram.com/670309656726033) page (same page link you have given in your question):

> You can always report strange emails to `phish@instagram.com`.

So, you don't have to click on the link in your email. You can forward this mail to Instagram directly.